# Python: df.iloc incorrectly reads column past 100

Tags: python

I have a file that looks like this:

```
  ID Ah Am  RAs  Ed Em  DEs   Vmag    U-B    B-V    V-I    e_    e_    e_    e_ _ _ _ _ mb n_ 2MASS
   1 10 42 57.6 -59 47 22.6 18.681         1.105  1.461 0.002       0.103 0.053 2 0 1 2       10425765-5947229
   2 10 42 57.7 -59 44 22.2 18.303                2.764 0.012             0.013 2 0 0 2
   3 10 42 57.7 -59 46 58.0 18.610                1.573 0.038             0.039 2 0 0 2       10425776-5946583
   4 10 42 57.8 -59 47 49.5 12.870         0.764  0.799 0.009       0.009 0.009 3 0 1 3       10425773-5947495
   5 10 42 57.8 -59 44 03.4 18.815         1.072  1.433 0.017       0.110 0.043 2 0 1 2
   6 10 42 57.8 -59 48 29.3 18.697                1.304 0.014             0.019 2 0 0 2       10425778-5948293
   7 10 42 57.8 -59 44 08.5 17.817         1.700  2.384 0.011       0.108 0.013 2 0 1 2       10425786-5944083
   8 10 42 57.9 -59 43 11.1 18.621         0.925  1.322 0.014       0.084 0.014 2 0 1 2
   9 10 42 58.0 -59 41 34.4 16.993         0.998  1.742 0.003       0.027 0.003 3 0 1 3       10425799-5941342
  10 10 42 58.0 -59 49 23.3 16.981         0.656  1.043 0.023       0.034 0.023 3 0 1 3       10425796-5949235
  11 10 42 58.1 -59 48 20.2 17.047         0.926  1.003 0.009       0.034 0.017 3 0 1 3
  12 10 42 58.1 -59 47 51.5 17.535         0.879  1.197 0.008       0.071 0.035 2 0 1 2
  13 10 42 58.2 -59 47 16.9 15.982         0.854  1.146 0.006       0.011 0.008 3 0 1 3       10425820-5947169
  14 10 42 58.2 -59 36 10.2 18.855                1.376 0.051             0.069 2 0 0 2
  15 10 42 58.2 -59 49 29.5 17.959         0.830  1.229 0.027       0.060 0.027 2 0 1 2       10425821-5949297
  16 10 42 58.2 -59 45 39.7 18.556         1.114  1.520 0.001       0.103 0.007 2 0 1 2
  17 10 42 58.3 -59 48 59.5 18.659         1.252  2.013 0.000       0.126 0.018 2 0 1 2       10425824-5948595
  18 10 42 58.3 -59 48 17.9 15.417         0.707  0.874 0.002       0.010 0.002 3 0 1 3       10425825-5948180
  19 10 42 58.3 -59 39 51.6 16.899         1.050  1.204 0.009       0.026 0.010 3 0 1 3       10425833-5939512
  20 10 42 58.3 -59 42 39.3 18.011         1.016  1.452 0.002       0.068 0.014 2 0 1 2       10425834-5942390
  21 10 42 58.4 -59 49 23.4 16.934         1.220  1.303 0.001       0.036 0.008 3 0 1 3       10425835-5949234
  22 10 42 58.4 -59 33 22.0 18.454                1.270 0.008             0.008 2 0 0 2
  23 10 42 58.5 -59 45 53.5 17.132         0.713  1.009 0.003       0.019 0.013 3 0 1 3       10425847-5945533
  24 10 42 58.5 -59 41 07.7 15.945         0.714  0.848 0.009       0.012 0.009 3 0 1 3       10425848-5941075
  25 10 42 58.5 -59 47 31.9 15.237         0.509  0.831 0.013       0.014 0.016 3 0 1 3       10425849-5947319
  26 10 42 58.6 -59 33 10.0 17.673         0.780  1.039 0.002       0.028 0.006 2 0 1 2       10425859-5933096
  27 10 42 58.6 -59 31 47.4 14.870         0.775  0.872 0.006       0.008 0.006 3 0 1 3       10425857-5931470
  28 10 42 58.7 -59 46 57.0 15.561         0.640  0.958 0.011       0.014 0.011 3 0 1 3       10425864-5946570
  29 10 42 58.7 -59 43 00.1 18.012         0.831  1.304 0.040       0.064 0.041 2 0 1 2       10425873-5942599
  30 10 42 58.7 -59 44 36.0 18.295         1.142  1.135 0.026       0.075 0.034 2 0 1 2       10425874-5944358
  31 10 42 58.8 -59 46 15.6 18.672         1.120  1.369 0.022       0.098 0.023 2 0 1 2       10425878-5946154
  32 10 42 58.9 -59 45 16.9 18.721         1.264  1.850 0.074       0.206 0.076 2 0 1 2
  33 10 42 58.9 -59 45 14.5 15.257         0.534  0.610 0.006       0.008 0.013 3 0 1 3       10425893-5945145
  34 10 42 59.0 -59 48 50.6 16.243         0.771  0.886 0.006       0.016 0.007 3 0 1 3       10425895-5948506
  35 10 42 59.1 -59 47 16.1 17.801         1.192  1.554 0.010       0.055 0.014 2 0 1 2       10425903-5947163
  36 10 42 59.1 -59 38 35.4 17.166         0.891  1.093 0.008       0.029 0.012 3 0 1 3       10425915-5938351
  37 10 42 59.1 -59 40 24.2 18.945         1.143  1.579 0.039       0.148 0.042 2 0 1 2
  38 10 42 59.1 -59 35 43.8 16.399         1.114  1.234 0.005       0.017 0.013 3 0 1 3       10425916-5935434
  39 10 42 59.2 -59 45 29.6 18.936                1.760 0.030             0.030 2 0 0 2       10425920-5945295
  40 10 42 59.2 -59 35 36.5 14.873         0.713  0.925 0.005       0.007 0.009 3 0 1 3       10425920-5935361
  41 10 42 59.3 -59 45 01.2 18.147         1.245  1.925 0.015       0.076 0.017 2 0 1 2       10425926-5945010
  42 10 42 59.3 -59 46 26.5 17.564         0.880  1.266 0.015       0.042 0.016 2 0 1 2       10425928-5946265
  43 10 42 59.4 -59 37 44.8 17.800         1.234  1.328 0.008       0.054 0.014 2 0 1 2       10425941-5937445
  44 10 42 59.4 -59 45 03.7 17.620         0.750  1.135 0.013       0.036 0.021 2 0 1 2
  45 10 42 59.4 -59 39 29.8 15.684         0.910  1.059 0.011       0.015 0.012 3 0 1 3    X  10425945-5939295
  46 10 42 59.5 -59 49 29.2 18.021         1.000  1.443 0.026       0.068 0.040 2 0 1 2       10425944-5949292
  47 10 42 59.5 -59 35 27.1 16.715         0.846  1.028 0.007       0.016 0.014 3 0 1 3       10425949-5935268
  48 10 42 59.5 -59 46 50.2 18.516         1.036  1.562 0.007       0.094 0.017 2 0 1 2       10425951-5946500
  49 10 42 59.5 -59 47 50.0 17.252         1.235  1.410 0.004       0.044 0.011 3 0 1 3       10425949-5947498
  50 10 42 59.5 -59 43 28.7 15.099         0.813  0.912 0.002       0.007 0.006 3 0 1 3       10425955-5943285
  51 10 42 59.5 -59 45 10.1 18.403         1.332  1.434 0.000       0.121 0.032 2 0 1 2       10425963-5945113
  52 10 42 59.6 -59 50 06.7 16.377         0.863  1.134 0.009       0.013 0.012 2 0 1 2       10425952-5950070
  53 10 42 59.6 -59 42 40.9 16.764         0.852  0.953 0.017       0.025 0.018 3 0 1 3       10425959-5942406
  54 10 42 59.7 -59 41 09.2 16.044         0.840  0.976 0.010       0.017 0.012 3 0 1 3       10425970-5941090
  55 10 42 59.7 -59 45 49.3 17.404         0.995  1.303 0.011       0.039 0.016 3 0 1 3    X  10425971-5945491
  56 10 42 59.8 -59 46 19.4 18.976         0.655        0.030       0.112       2 0 1 0       10425983-5946194
  57 10 42 59.8 -59 48 30.6 18.105         1.104  1.623 0.013       0.046 0.027 3 0 2 3       10425977-5948308
  58 10 42 59.9 -59 35 21.1 16.252         0.804  0.981 0.002       0.014 0.009 3 0 1 3       10425992-5935208
  59 10 42 59.9 -59 40 25.0 17.636         1.100  1.284 0.031       0.053 0.034 2 0 1 2       10425996-5940248
  60 10 43 00.0 -59 38 11.3 17.689         0.901  1.183 0.010       0.032 0.016 2 0 1 2       10430002-5938110
  61 10 43 00.0 -59 48 06.1 16.885         1.456  2.054 0.005       0.022 0.005 5 0 2 5       10425997-5948062
  62 10 43 00.0 -59 47 40.1 18.460         0.927  1.518 0.018       0.048 0.030 3 0 2 3
  63 10 43 00.0 -59 45 28.7 18.419                3.654 0.022             0.022 3 0 0 3       10430004-5945287
  64 10 43 00.2 -59 38 22.3 17.662         0.954  1.176 0.001       0.036 0.008 2 0 1 2       10430020-5938221
  65 10 43 00.2 -59 40 59.6 17.491         1.203  2.039 0.028       0.050 0.030 2 0 1 2       10430022-5940594
  66 10 43 00.2 -59 33 10.1 17.907         1.331  1.786 0.019       0.062 0.019 2 0 1 2       10430023-5933097
  67 10 43 00.2 -59 49 44.3 18.154         1.263  1.613 0.019       0.066 0.036 1 0 1 1
  68 10 43 00.3 -59 43 37.2 17.570         0.990  1.388 0.013       0.028 0.017 3 0 2 3
  69 10 43 00.5 -59 47 56.8 18.473         0.842  1.330 0.029       0.051 0.073 3 0 2 3
  70 10 43 00.5 -59 48 51.6 14.723  0.306  0.621  0.933 0.001 0.041 0.006 0.002 5 1 3 5    X  10430051-5948517
  71 10 43 00.6 -59 48 02.3 18.109         1.035  1.634 0.020       0.040 0.023 3 0 2 3       10430057-5948024
  72 10 43 00.6 -59 42 34.0 18.825                2.358 0.029             0.034 3 0 0 3       10430061-5942339
  73 10 43 00.6 -59 43 38.0 15.399 -0.143  0.607  1.006 0.003 0.050 0.005 0.004 5 1 3 5       10430060-5943379
  74 10 43 00.6 -59 31 46.5 15.261         0.716  0.856 0.009       0.011 0.009 3 0 1 3       10430060-5931461
  75 10 43 00.6 -59 41 26.2 18.594         1.282  1.777 0.013       0.077 0.019 3 0 2 3
  76 10 43 00.7 -59 46 34.2 18.329         1.081  1.559 0.017       0.052 0.018 3 0 2 3       10430064-5946341
  77 10 43 00.7 -59 42 51.9 17.958         1.109  1.866 0.010       0.037 0.012 3 0 2 3       10430070-5942515
  78 10 43 00.7 -59 44 31.0 16.746         0.935  1.010 0.007       0.015 0.014 5 0 2 5       10430074-5944309
  79 10 43 00.7 -59 48 58.1 17.545         0.950  1.388 0.014       0.027 0.024 4 0 2 4       10430071-5948583
  80 10 43 00.8 -59 38 29.5 14.756         1.251  1.366 0.010       0.017 0.013 4 0 2 4       10430078-5938292
  81 10 43 00.8 -59 46 44.5 18.183         0.885  1.241 0.010       0.039 0.017 3 0 2 3       10430082-5946448
  82 10 43 00.9 -59 47 05.1 18.965                2.599 0.027             0.031 3 0 0 3       10430090-5947052
  83 10 43 01.0 -59 42 24.6 12.054 -0.253  0.048  0.125 0.007 0.013 0.009 0.008 4 1 2 4       10430098-5942245
  84 10 43 01.0 -59 49 13.8 18.902                1.975 0.040             0.048 3 0 0 3    X  10430097-5949144
  85 10 43 01.0 -59 49 58.4 16.394         0.878  1.085 0.003       0.020 0.022 2 0 2 2
  86 10 43 01.0 -59 49 55.4 15.608         0.577  0.856 0.004       0.004 0.004 2 0 2 2       10430096-5949562
  87 10 43 01.1 -59 49 26.0 18.979         1.186  1.601 0.022       0.127 0.062 3 0 1 3       10430104-5949266
  88 10 43 01.1 -59 45 48.4 15.181  0.224  0.537  0.683 0.004 0.053 0.005 0.004 5 1 3 5       10430105-5945484
  89 10 43 01.2 -59 44 05.3 18.192         1.026  1.399 0.011       0.043 0.014 3 0 2 3
  90 10 43 01.2 -59 36 31.4 16.007         0.715  0.916 0.004       0.006 0.011 5 0 3 5       10430119-5936312
  91 10 43 01.2 -59 47 56.0 18.049         1.070  1.273 0.012       0.037 0.016 3 0 2 3       10430116-5947561
  92 10 43 01.2 -59 29 36.1 16.088         0.771  0.966 0.009       0.015 0.010 3 0 1 3       10430117-5929355
  93 10 43 01.2 -59 44 30.7 17.023         0.891  1.210 0.007       0.016 0.012 5 0 2 5       10430126-5944307
  94 10 43 01.3 -59 49 15.1 17.647         0.792  1.155 0.015       0.029 0.018 3 0 2 3
  95 10 43 01.3 -59 41 33.5 17.639         1.063  1.802 0.008       0.026 0.010 3 0 2 3       10430129-5941334
  96 10 43 01.3 -59 47 30.0 13.687  0.268  0.772  0.822 0.004 0.021 0.004 0.004 5 1 3 5       10430129-5947300
  97 10 43 01.3 -59 47 52.1 17.616         1.088  1.305 0.008       0.031 0.011 3 0 2 3       10430132-5947523
  98 10 43 01.4 -59 46 36.9 18.866         0.863  1.346 0.018       0.067 0.045 3 0 1 3
  99 10 43 01.4 -59 43 22.7 18.847         1.341  1.556 0.025       0.149 0.035 3 0 1 3       10430137-5943226
 100 10 43 01.4 -59 44 34.0 18.599         1.232  1.635 0.021       0.068 0.024 3 0 1 3
 101 10 43 01.4 -59 47 24.2 18.907                1.395 0.022             0.031 3 0 0 3
 102 10 43 01.5 -59 42 55.1 18.873                3.068 0.023             0.026 3 0 0 3       10430151-5942549
 103 10 43 01.5 -59 47 42.1 14.828  0.206  0.599  0.725 0.007 0.034 0.008 0.008 5 1 3 5       10430149-5947422
```

I have included a little more than the first 100 columns to illustrate the issue.

I tried  to read the file in with pandas and then initialize a list with the 'ID' column.

```
df = pd.read_fwf('Hur_et_al_2012_catalog/table1.dat')
IDs = df.iloc[:, 0]
```

Yet, I notice beyond ID 100, the values are incorrectly read and repeat themselves `IDs[102]` for example yields `3` instead of `103`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with `infer_nrows` parameter.

`pd.read_fwf("filename.dat", infer_nrows=101)` works for your problem. From index 99 in continues with 100 and so on instead of counter resetting to 0.

Btw, you don't need to use `df.iloc` to get the column values, `df.ID` works as well.